# Select multiple jQuery objects with .add()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method allow selecting multiple objects in one go instead of adding one at a time?

```
one.add(two).add(three).add(four).on("click", function() { });
```

The following variables are set in the way they do because each carries a different function.

```
var one   = $("#1");
var two   = $("#2");
var three = $("#3");
var four  = $("#4");
```

But what if I want to add an extra function that applies to all of these elements? Do I have to add them one by one?

I know you can select them all using `$("#1,#2,#3,#4")`, but I just want to make use of the above variables.

Comment: BTW: A number as first character for ID-declaration is never a good idea... ;-)

Comment: @yckart They are never named that way. This is for the purpose of illustration only.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'd prefer this array approach, purely for readability...

```
$([one, two, three, four]).each(function() {
    // your function here
});
```

Answer (score 11):

You cannot add multiple objects in one go, for example:

```
var groupThree = one.add(three, five); // will not work as expected
```

You could cache the added objects so that you only have to do the add one time - http://jsfiddle.net/X5432/

```
var one   = $("#1");
var two   = $("#2");
var three = $("#3");
var four  = $("#4");
var five  = $("#5");

var groupOne = one.add(two).add(three).add(four);
var groupTwo = groupOne.add(five);

$('#first').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    groupOne.css({'background': '#00FF00'});
});

$('#second').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    groupTwo.css({'background': '#FF0000'});
});
```

But I like the array method better, this is just a different way of thinking about it.

Comment: This is nice, you might get even more benefit from the approach by using it like: `groupOne.click(function(e){});`

Answer (score 5):

You could put them into an array like this

```
var k = [one,two,three,four]

$.each(k,function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
     //Function here
   });
});
```

Comment: Or just do this: `$(k).click(function(){...})`