# How to select multiple jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

Like if I wanted to select both document and window elements.

```
$(window, document).doStuff();
```

Doesn't work. Probably because according to the docs, 2nd argument is some "context" thing...

Basically I'm just looking for an alternative too

```
$(window).doStuff();
$(document).doStuff();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select multiple jQuery objects with .add()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627330/select-multiple-jquery-objects-with-add)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var one   = $("#1");
var two   = $("#2");
var three = $("#3");
var four  = $("#4");



 $([one, two, three, four]).each(function() {
        // your function here
    });
```

The `document ready` event executes already when the `HTML-Document` is loaded and the `DOM` is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet.

If you want to hook up your events for certain elements before the window loads, then `$(document).ready` is the right place.

Comment: Note that `one` `two` `three` and `four` can't be jQuery objects. (well, they can, but it will have unexpected results)

Comment: doubt, doesn't having something done in `$(window)` will automatically be done in `$(document)` too?

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
//executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
while 
$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: @user1145009 With the update, your question is now going to have unexpected results. `this` inside the each will instead be a jQuery object rather than the dom node. Not necessarily a problem if that's intended, but it's out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).add(document).doStuff();
```