# .removeClass on multiple items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Can I rewrite the code below to something less repetitive?

```
    $("#iTUNES").click(function()
{
    createLastEdition(26);
    $("#Beatport").removeClass("Active");
    $("#Spotify").removeClass("Active");
    $("#Youtube").removeClass("Active");
    $("#iTunes").addClass("Active");
});
```

For example something like this

```
$("#Beatport","#Spotify,"#Youtube").removeClass("Active")
```

?

Comment: So, `$("#Beatport,#Spotify,#Youtube").removeClass("Active") `

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select multiple jQuery objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132648/how-to-select-multiple-jquery-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine selectors with standard CSS syntax:

```
$("#Beatport, #Spotify, #Youtube, #iTunes").removeClass("Active");
```

You might find it more convenient to categorize such related page elements with a class. Then you'd just need

```
$(".media-container").removeClass("Active");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use active class itself to remove active class

```
$(".Active").removeClass("Active");
$("#iTunes").addClass("Active");
```

Answer (score 0):

These should work :

```
$("#Beatport","#Spotify","#Youtube").removeClass("Active");
```

or

```
$("#Beatport,#Spotify,#Youtube").removeClass("Active");
```