# How to use multiple jquery object variables as selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery, selecting more than one element can be done like this:

```
$("#id1,#id2").show();
```

But when I have two jQuery objects, I don't seem to be able to select more than one using the variables themselves. For example:

```
var jqId1 = $("#id1");
var jqId2 = $("#id2");
$(jqId1).show();       // This works.
$(jqId1,jqId2).show(); // This only shows jqId1.
```

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jr9Q2/

Is there another way of specifying multiple jq variables as selectors?

Comment: check this  http://jsfiddle.net/jr9Q2/4/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) :

```
jqId1.add(jqId2).show();
```

But don't make your code too complex just to avoid querying `"#id1,#id2"` : this selector relies on `getElementById` and is very fast.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid repeating the selector string, but of course it can go into a variable if that's the most efficient way.

Comment: I might have been unclear : Using `$("#id1,#id2")` isn't the most efficient way. I just wanted to point that you shouldn't worry for performances here, but you should use what makes your code readable and simple.

Comment: Thanks again. Just discovered the `selector` property, so now it's `$(jqId1.selector+','+jqId2.selector)`. :)

Comment: `jqId1.add(jqId2)` would be faster (which isn't important) and in my opinion clearer than `$(jqId1.selector+','+jqId2.selector)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use each cycle:

```
$([jqId1, jqId2]).each( function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

As answered here:
[Select multiple jQuery objects with .add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627330/select-multiple-jquery-objects-with-add)

Answer (score 0):

I know this sound a little stupid, but you can also try like this.

```
$([
    jqId1.get(0),
    jqId2.get(0),
    jqId3.get(0),
    ... // more jQuery elements
]).show();
```