# Each function - multi select

Tags: jquery, href, each

just little question.

Is it the right way to use "," for separation here?

```
$('a[href*="-001&"]','a[href*="-005&"]').each(function () { });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple jquery object variables as selectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504075/how-to-use-multiple-jquery-object-variables-as-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href*="-001&"], a[href*="-005&"]').each(function () { });
```

Use the comma inside the string.

[Multiple Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not correct.
If you need both selectors to work, then just open quotes, enumerate all the selectors through the comma, and than close the quotes.

It's called **[Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**  in jQuery, check the manual.

Correct could would be:

```
$('a[href*="-001&"], a[href*="-005&"]').each(function () { });
```